# iOS: Instance Values change between method call

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to implement a custom implementation of switching buttons so that only one can be selected at a time. I have run into a weird error where I init an object using `[[ajdSwitchButton alloc] init]`. In the init I set a class property as follows `self.currentSelection = 2`.

The issue is that between the `init` and the first call to an `IBAction` method, the value is changed to 0. I cannot figure out why. Here is the relevant code:

`ajdSwitchButton.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ajdSwitchButton : UIView

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger currentSelection;

// Button Outlets
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonOne;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonTwo;

// Button Actions
- (IBAction)buttonPress:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)buttonPressTwo:(id)sender;

// Instance Methods
- (void)switchButtonState:(UIButton *)button;

@end
```

`ajdSwitchButton.m`

```
#import "ajdSwitchButton.h"

@implementation ajdSwitchButton

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        _currentSelection = 2;
    }
    return self;
}

// Handles button press actions for buttonOne
- (IBAction)buttonPress:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%@", self);
    // Y button pressed
    if (self.currentSelection == 2) {
        // No button is selected
        // Highlight and select buttonOne
        [self performSelector:@selector(switchButtonState:) withObject:self.buttonOne afterDelay:0.0];
    } else if (self.currentSelection == 1) {
        // No was previously selected
        // Unselect NO and select YES
        [self performSelector:@selector(switchButtonState:) withObject:self.buttonTwo afterDelay:0.0];
        [self performSelector:@selector(switchButtonState:) withObject:self.buttonOne afterDelay:0.0];
    } else {
    // Y button already pressed
    [self performSelector:@selector(switchButtonState:) withObject:self.buttonOne afterDelay:0.0];
    }
    self.currentSelection = 0;
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressTwo:(id)sender {
    // N button pressed
    NSLog(@"%i", self.currentSelection);
    if (self.currentSelection == 2) {
        // No button is selected
        // Highlight and select buttonOne
    [self performSelector:@selector(switchButtonState:) withObject:self.buttonTwo afterDelay:0.0];
} else if (self.currentSelection == 0) {
        // Yes was previously selected
        // Unselect YES and select NO
        [self performSelector:@selector(switchButtonState:) withObject:self.buttonTwo afterDelay:0.0];
        [self performSelector:@selector(switchButtonState:) withObject:self.buttonOne afterDelay:0.0];
    } else {
        // N button already pressed
        [self performSelector:@selector(switchButtonState:) withObject:self.buttonTwo afterDelay:0.0];
    }
    self.currentSelection = 1;
}

// Switches the look and state of the button
- (void)switchButtonState:(UIButton *)button {
    if (!button.selected) {
        button.highlighted = YES;
        button.selected = YES;
    } else {
        button.highlighted = NO;
        button.selected = NO;
    }
}
@end
```

I link an instance of `ajdSwitchButton` to an `IBOutlet` view within `ViewController`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I pasted some NSLogs to check the memory value of the object directly after the `init` and as soon as the `IBAction` method is called. Here is the before and after:

`<ajdSwitchButton: 0x746d2e0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x7472c40>>`

`<ajdSwitchButton: 0x7471b10; frame = (77 232; 180 83); autoresize = TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7471bf0>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBOutlets init through initWithCoder:(NSCoder)aDecoder, so you need to implement this method.

```c
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        _currentSelection = 2;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This absolutely worked. The problem I have now is that I have several books on iOS Development and have not even heard of this method. I have ran a few projects just fine without `initWithCoder` for `IBOutlets`. I will definitely be reading up more. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it in your code...

That might be a silly mistake or you need that.. please check your code :

```
- (IBAction)buttonPress:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%@", self);
    // Y button pressed
    if (self.currentSelection == 2) {
        // No button is selected
        // Highlight and select buttonOne
        [self performSelector:@selector(switchButtonState:) withObject:self.buttonOne afterDelay:0.0];
    } else if (self.currentSelection == 1) {
        // No was previously selected
        // Unselect NO and select YES
        [self performSelector:@selector(switchButtonState:) withObject:self.buttonTwo afterDelay:0.0];
        [self performSelector:@selector(switchButtonState:) withObject:self.buttonOne afterDelay:0.0];
    } else {
    // Y button already pressed
    [self performSelector:@selector(switchButtonState:) withObject:self.buttonOne afterDelay:0.0];
    }



    /*  SEE HERE */

    self.currentSelection = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. That didn't resolve the issue. I did notice a possible issue in memory that may help out. I will update it in the original post.

Comment: It is 0 before it even gets to that line. After setting the variable to 2, the method should go straight to `if (self.currentSelection == 2)`, but instead it changes back to 0 and executes the code under the last `else` clause. I commented that line out just to be sure, but the issue still persists.

Comment: Why dont you initialize in viewDidLoad method?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your question itself.

You are initializing the variable in:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
}
```

You already mentioned that you are creating the object using `[[ajdSwitchButton alloc] init]`.

You are calling `init` not `initWithFrame` so the variable never get initialized.
So implement a function like:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        _currentSelection = 2;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I used `- (id)init` instead of `- (id)initWithFrame:` and it still changes values as soon as I make the first button press.